# Can you access a private [static] nested class through a public nested interface?

Tags: java, oop

Okay, here's the setup:

```
EnclosingClass {

    public interface ClassFactory {
        public static SomeClass getInstance(int which);
    }

    private static ClassFactoryImpl {
        @Override
        public static SomeClass getInstance(int which) {
            switch(which) {
            case 1:
                return new SomeClassSubclassA();
            case 2:
                return new SomeClassSubclassB();
            ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to issue statements along the line of:

```
SomeClass x = EnclosingClass.ClassFactory.getInstance(instanceClassRequest);
```

Is this possible?  If not, how can I access a static nested class through only the interface it implements?

Comment: ...`ClassFactory` is an interface, not a class, and `getInstance` isn't a static method.  So you couldn't write a statement like `EnclosingClass.ClassFactory.getInstance` the way you've done it...

Comment: @LouisWasserman changed it.  They were supposed to be `static`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman but yes, the question is how can I access a nested class through its interface..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "no."  You'll need to make an *instance* of your implementation class and put it in a static variable.  It'll look like this:

```
public class EnclosingClass {
    public interface ClassFactory {
        public SomeClass getInstance(int which);
    }
    public static final ClassFactory CLASS_FACTORY;

    private static class ClassFactoryImpl implements ClassFactory {
        public SomeClass getInstance(int which) { /* ... */ }
    }

    static {
        CLASS_FACTORY = new ClassFactoryImpl();
    }
}
```

Also note that the method on the instance is no longer static.

Then code that invokes it would look like this:

```
SomeClass x = EnclosingClass.CLASS_FACTORY.getInstance(2);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking too.  However, I was caught up on the `new ClassFactoryImpl();` part.  Is it appropriate to construct a new instance of a static class -- in other words, is that normal, valid, and okay?

Comment: Yes, it's appropriate.  The "static" modifier on that private inner class is a little misleading.  All it means in this case is that each `ClassFactoryImpl` instance is not attached to a particular instance of `EnclosingClass`.  It's not like the `static` keyword in C or C++.  If ClassFactoryImpl were in a separate ".java" file of its own, it would not have the "static" in its class declaration.

Comment: Interesting!  I wasn't sure of the finer details about the difference between static nested classes and inner classes so I found this [question on the difference between static nested classes and inner classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class), which is also helpful.